# FIR filtering with C++ to a sinewave

Tags: finite-impulse-response, c, c++

I am translating my FIR filter script from python to C++. My problem is that I am following a workflow which in theory should work but I get weird results.

1st. I create a signal from 1 and 50 Hz sine waves: The sampling frequency is 2KHz.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fs = 2000
t = 10
f1 = 1 #Hz
f2 = 50 #Hz 
samples = t*fs
t = np.linspace(0, samples, samples)
def SineGenerator():
    signal = np.sin(f1 * 2 * np.pi * t) + 0.5 * np.sin(f2 * 2 * np.pi * t)
    data = np.zeros((samples,2), dtype=int)
    data[:,0] = t
    data[:,1] = signal
    np.savetxt('sine.dat', data, fmt='%d')
    plt.plot(t, signal)
```

2nd: I create FIR filter coefficients manually (yes, I prefer using my own maths):

```
fs = 2000  # 1000 Hz sampling rate
ntaps = 200

# Define the frequencies for the FIR filter
f0 = 1
f1 = 45
f2 = 55

FIRfrequencyResponse = np.ones(ntaps)
# Limits for the filtering
k0 = int((f0 / fs) * ntaps)
k1 = int((f1 / fs) * ntaps)
k2 = int((f2 / fs) * ntaps)

FIRfrequencyResponse[k1:k2 + 1] = 0
FIRfrequencyResponse[ntaps - k2:ntaps - k1 + 1] = 0
FIRfrequencyResponse[0:k0 + 1] = 0
FIRfrequencyResponse[ntaps - k0:ntaps] = 0

timeFIR = np.fft.ifft(FIRfrequencyResponse)
h_real = np.real(timeFIR)
FIR_shifted = np.zeros(ntaps)
FIR_shifted[0:int(ntaps / 2)] = h_real[int(ntaps / 2):ntaps]
FIR_shifted[int(ntaps / 2):ntaps] = h_real[0:int(ntaps / 2)]
FIR_shifted_scaled = FIR_shifted*(2**8) // Scaled to use fixed point implementation later on C++
np.savetxt('coefficients.dat', [FIR_shifted_scaled] , fmt='%f', delimiter=', ')
```

3rd: my c++ script:

```
# include <iostream>

int length = 20000;
float bufferFIR[100] = {0};  
float coeffFIR[100] = {
  -2.560000, -2.649736, -2.904523, -3.282859, -3.721266,
  -4.142167, -4.463654, -4.610068, -4.522177, -4.165799,
  -3.537833, -2.668954, -1.622540, -0.489833, 0.618289,
   1.582167, 2.285778, 2.629450, 2.541559, 1.987922,
   0.977833, -0.434024, -2.150152, -4.037230, -5.936979,
  -7.680000, -9.101313, -10.056151, -10.434486, -10.172843,
  -9.262167, -7.750897, -5.742775, -3.389471, -0.878556,
   1.582167, 3.782623, 5.529088, 6.661794, 7.069865,
   6.702167, 5.573020, 3.762157, 1.408853, -1.299320,
  -4.142167, -6.885600, -9.301780, -11.188857, -12.388555,
 243.200000, -12.388555, -11.188857, -9.301780, -6.885600,
  -4.142167, -1.299320, 1.408853, 3.762157, 5.573020,
   6.702167, 7.069865, 6.661794, 5.529088, 3.782623,
   1.582167, -0.878556, -3.389471, -5.742775, -7.750897,
  -9.262167, -10.172843, -10.434486, -10.056151, -9.101313,
  -7.680000, -5.936979, -4.037230, -2.150152, -0.434024,
   0.977833, 1.987922, 2.541559, 2.629450, 2.285778,
   1.582167, 0.618289, -0.489833, -1.622540, -2.668954,
  -3.537833, -4.165799, -4.522177, -4.610068, -4.463654,
  -4.142167, -3.721266, -3.282859, -2.904523, -2.649736};   
float input[20000] = {0};
int taps = 100;
float out[20000] = {0};  

float filter(float value){
    float output = 0;     
    for(int i=taps-1;i>0;i--){
        bufferFIR[i] = bufferFIR[i-1]; 
    } 
    bufferFIR[0] = value;
    for(int i=0;i<taps;i++){
        output += bufferFIR[i]*coeffFIR[i];  
    }   
    return output;
} 

using namespace std;
int main(){
    FILE *finput = fopen("sine.dat","rt");
    int t, x; 
    if (!finput){
        printf("oops, file can't be read\n");
        exit(-1);
    } 

    while ( fscanf(finput, "%d %d\n", &t, &x ) >1 ){ 
        printf("%d %d\n", t, x); 
        input[t] = x; 
    }   
    for(int i=0;i<=length-1;i++){
        out[i] = filter(input[i]);  
    }

    FILE *foutput = fopen("output.dat","wt");
    for(int i =0; i<length-1;i++){
        fprintf(foutput,"%f\n", out[i]);
    } 
    fclose(foutput);
    fclose(finput);
}
```

However, in my C script I am reading that signal from the .dat file I storaged it and filtering with a convolution function but I cannot get any result! The 50 Hz component is not removed and everything is kind of strange output. I don't know what I made wrong. I think that the convolution is ok, I can plot the impulse response with an impulse signal storaged in the same file that I am using as input and everything goes well. Might it be the sampling frequency or anything else? I plot the figure of my result.

[image]

This is also kinda discussion but, since I am implementing everything on C++ on onyl one script, I am looking for more robust and efficient ways of doing these operations. You might wonder why I am not using hierarchies and classes? I want to pass all of this to rac C later on cause I need to implement it on a DSP microcontroller.

Thanks in advance to all! and sorry for all the code!

Update:
I tried what TimWescott suggested and on Python script works perfectly:
[image]

However, on the Cpp script I still get weird things like:

[image]

Solved: The issue with the filtering was with the floating point numbers. While scaling up might be helpful, on floating numbers it seems that it changes a lot the response of the filter (because it changes coefficients quite a lot) So my solution is to change data type and to unscale coefficients.
thanks to all contributing to the post.

Comment: All my embedded microcontroller work, except for the exceedingly small apps, is done with C++.  You just need to be aware of what features of C++ demand work from the compiler but not the runtime, and confine yourself to those.

Comment: I am sure I can run it on C+++ but I want to make it as simple as possible. Anyway, the issue right now is why the filtering is working wrong. Will use c++ if I can for sure!

Comment: Have you tested the filter in Python?  Did it work?  I'd do that, or I'd fill the filter buffer with ones and test that (the frequency response should be $200\ \mathrm{sync}\ 4 \pi f$)

Comment: Nice idea! I tried it on python and it works perfectly. I have to say that I changed some parameters so I would need to reconsider re-running the python script. About filling the buffer of the filter, what should I except? Like, it will be  200 sync 4πf for sure?

Comment: It will absolutely positively be $200\,\mathrm{sync}\, 4 \pi f$ for sure -- unless I got my math wrong.  If your code is running right it *will* be a sync function, and it will have nulls every 2Hz -- I can tell you that much.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that the reason you're doing this is to find where the problem is -- you now know it's not your filter definition, but rather the implementation.  I think I'd still be tempted to give it the all-ones filter, though -- that ends up being a simple running average, and something that you can debug by hand if necessary.

Comment: You are right! I will have a look into it again and see if the implementation is wrong. then. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116611/discussion-between-gabriel-galeote-checa-and-timwescott).

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, it helped a lot! I found a slight solution to the problem. Gonna head to the lab again.